# Centering a link with image in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the image inside the link:

```
<a href="URL">
   <img class="my_class" src="SRC" />
</a>
```

The css looks like:

```
.my_class
{
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

My problem is that the link can be pressed on the whole width of the page in the specific height and not only on my image. Also, my application needs to work with both directions: `dir:"rtl"` and `dir:"ltr"`

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you're dealing with? Your CSS feels incomplete, where's the anchor's styling?

Comment: what do you mean by image at center of link? you have not assigned your link any dimensions. by default the image will occupy the whole space of link

Comment: The example below (DEMO) shows my problem: the link on the image can be pressed from the sides of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean like [this?](http://jsfiddle.net/wK8gs/8/)

Just put `width` and `height` property.

`width: 200px; height: 150px; /*Example*/`

Answer (score 3):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wK8gs/2/)**

**HTML**

```
<a href="URL" class="my_class">
   <img src="SRC" />
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-align:center;
}
.my_class {
  position:relative;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

**[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/wK8gs/7/)**

**CSS**

```
   iframe, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: (+1) I'm deleting my answer because this is much better.

Comment: The problem is (see your example) that you can press on the link from the left / right sides of the image

Comment: What solve my question is do add a div container with the class

Comment: @crazybob i think without div you should add .my_class in 'a' tag  i think this is the right way.

Comment: I agree, but i can't make it right. look at your demo, it's not working.

Comment: Still, the link can be pressed outside the image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36515/discussion-between-fags-and-crazybob)

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather wrap it in a container like so:

```
<div class="my_class"><a href="#"><img src="src.png" /></a></div>
```

The CSS for `my_class` would remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
a {
   text-align: center; 
}
```

And remove this : 
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

Answer (score 0):

i think lots of padding right and left will solve your problem

like

```
a{
width:1000px;
background:red;
padding:10px 250px 10px 250px;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wK8gs/3/)**